# Are there any cards legal in Kamigawa Standard that would allow me to copy a legendary creature and keep the copy?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-standard

As the title says. I am playing in Standard format and am wanting to have two copies of a legendary creature on the battlefield at once. Is there any card that would legally allow me to do that? I'm in the Kamigawa: Neon Dynasty meta.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

https://www.mtggoldfish.com/price/Kamigawa+Neon+Dynasty/Mirror+Box#online

[image]

This is from the most recent set.

Comment: Echoing Equation from Strixhaven also works, albeit briefly

Answer (score 0):

I would use a search like scryfall and search for the text Legendary and pick the format as Standard. It also includes the term "nonlegendary", but it certainly cuts down how many cards you'll need to evaluate.

Cards I found:

[Delina, Wild Mage](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Delina%2C%20Wild%20Mage)

[Double Major](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Double%20Major)

[Echoing Equation](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Echoing%20Equation)